# want to make relations(between Event and Files)

Tags: google-app-engine

I am using `plupload` plugin to upload multiple files. That works fine.

In `Files` Model, I am storing the `user_id` and `blob_key`.
Here is [a form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lHQB1.jpg).

Suppose User's uploaded the files using plugin. That files are successfully saved in `FILES`. Then he submit the form. Now `description` field saved to `Event`. how do I know that event has this this files? There is no any relationship between `Event` and `Files` models. I am confused. So Will you please help me to create a relationship? thanks alot :-)

```
 class Files(db.Model):
      blob_key = blobstore.BlobReferenceProperty(required=True)
      created_by = xxxxxx
```

Here is my second Model

```
class Event(db.Model):
  description = db.StringProperty(required=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how you'd set a reference to from the Event to the File.

If you need the opposite, you can put a db.ReferenceProperty(Event) in the File class.

```
class Event(db.Model):
    description = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    file = db.ReferenceProperty(Files)
```

Comment: i think its easier to do it the other way around. put a reference to the event on each file. but of course this depends on how many files each event could have... if its only a few it doesnt matter... with a few 1000 i would put the reference on the file

Comment: @dragonx I think we can't put a db.ReferenceProperty in Files. Because I'm saving the `Files` first then `Event`. On the other way, `file = db.ReferenceProperty(Files)` it will save only one file. What about others? If user's uploading three files?

Comment: If you wanted to do it the other way around, you can update the file after you save the event, there shouldn't be a real reason why you can't do that.  You can have the 3 files all store the reference to the same event.

You could also use a ListProperty of ReferenceProperties.   The number of items in a list would be limited to the number of indexed properties in an entity, which I think is 3000 or 5000.

Comment: @dragonx Sorry Im bothering you. Is it better to generate key using `db.allocate_ids()`, then assign the new ID to an Entity? Suppose I will generate key for `Event` Model then I will store the files with that key. any suggestion. thanks

Comment: There's a few points here: a) you can definitely use a key instead of a ReferenceProperty, if that's what you're getting at.  b) it sounds like you want to create a key for the Event first using db.allocate_ids(), then create the File, and store the key in the file, then create the Event later?  Yes that can be done but it's confusing.  c) It seems like the straightforward option is to create the File, then either store a ReferenceProperty to the File, or the key from the File, when you create a new event.  I don't see db.allocate_ids() being necessary.